# Getting parent's parent from current node in Xpath 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I always seem to have trouble with xpath axis expressions...

In some expressions I have used `../` to refer to the parent node, but is that not valid for `test` expressions? Or is my syntax just wrong?

```
<xsl:when test="../../[@status='current']">
```

My goal is to apply an attribute inside the `xsl:when` IF the parent's parent has a status attribute with a value of 'current'.

EDIT: `self::parent/parent[@status='current']` is a valid xpath expression and may be what I want, can anyone confirm? I might not be going far enough.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is in `/[`. You can change it to

```
../../self::*[@status='current']
```

Comment: This did it. Can you please elaborate on my misunderstanding? From what I understand, `../../` selects the parent's parent, and `[@status]` then performs a test on the status attribute of that element.

Comment: @meder: `/` separates steps, so it cannot come before a predicate (the `[...]` part).

Comment: Right, the element isn't the [], it's the * (and [] just explains the attribute and value the * element must have)

Answer (score 7):

A simpler solution than those from choroba and Hansen is

```
../..[@status='current']
```

Comment: I swear I tried this and if memory serves right, it failed due to improper expression, but logically it works in my mind.

Comment: Agreed, that it is the most straightforward.  With XSLT/XPath 1.0 oXygen reports the following validation error: `E [Saxon6.5.5] Error in expression ../..[@status='current']: Unexpected token [ beyond end of expression`, but it still works when actually executing the transform. Validates fine as an XSLT/XPath 2.0.

Comment: I remembered that XPath 1.0 didn't allow a predicate after ".", but I had forgotten that it didn't allow it after ".." either. A completely pointless restriction, lifted in 2.0. In 1.0 replace ".." by "parent::node()".

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the following:

```
parent::*/parent::*[@status='current']
```

Comment: Great. Too bad PHP arrays can't do that.

Answer (score 3):

**With Xpath 2.0**:

```
 ../../@status eq 'current'
```

**With XPath 1.0 *and* XPath 2.0**:

```
 ../../@status = 'current'
```